# Is There A Way To Make Batch / Global Changes To IIS Zone Properties?

Tags: iis

Okay here's the scenario.. I've got a server in charge of DNS for close to a thousand websites and I need to make a change in IIS to the DNS Forward Lookup Zone settings. Right now on each domain I have to right-click, goto Properties, goto Name Server tab and add a domain name, then goto the Zone Transfers tab and check "Allow Zone Transfers" and select "Only to servers listed in the Name Servers tab". Yes that takes 30-45 seconds to do, but multiply that x 1000 and your looking at 10 hours of making all these edits.

I was hoping there was a way to batch process or globally change these properties, anyone have any ideas?